# Loss decreasing faster = lower convergence?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to optimize a generative deep LSTM network but I am unable to train each model until it converges because it would take a very long time and cost too much on AWS. I am grid searching through depths of hidden layers and number of nodes within those layers using the same same learning rate.  I intend to choose the model that produces the lowest loss for that limited training run on the 15th epoch because at that point they still have not converged.

Is this a good method? Namely, will the structure that trains the fastest converge at the lowest loss, or are there cases when a certain structure might reach a lower loss at a slower rate?

Comment: Hello Mevers,

Could you explain a bit on what you mean by structures and what is the outcome expected out of the network?

Comment: I edited the 1st post to clarify